# Unable to start docker container, "docker ps -a" STATUS = Exited (1)

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm trying to start a postgres instance as described in [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres).

To do that, I ran the following command:

```sh
sudo docker run --name database -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=supersecret -p 5432:5432 -d postgres
```

When I run `docker ps` it shows nothing, and when I run `docker ps -a` it shows:

```sh
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
967ebe7efb74        postgres            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 minutes ago       Exited (1) 2 minutes ago                        database
```

Trying to `docker start database` also leads to `STATUS Exited (1)` as displayed above.

Here are the logs displayed by `docker logs -f database`:

```sh
PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.

2019-09-10 14:08:26.941 UTC [1] LOG:  could not create IPv6 socket for address "::": Permission denied
2019-09-10 14:08:26.941 UTC [1] LOG:  could not create IPv4 socket for address "0.0.0.0": Permission denied
2019-09-10 14:08:26.941 UTC [1] WARNING:  could not create listen socket for "*"
2019-09-10 14:08:26.941 UTC [1] FATAL:  could not create any TCP/IP sockets
2019-09-10 14:08:26.941 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

In my research on the internet to solve this problem, some people said that it could be something with my hosts file, but it seems fine as shown below.

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   user-PC

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

I tried to reinstall docker following the [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/debian/) step-by-step tutorial, and I also did the [post installation steps](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/) without success.

OS: Deepin GNU/Linux 15.11
Docker: Docker version 18.09.6, build 481bc77

Comment: Do you have anything running on port 5432?

Comment: The reason should be apparmor. Try disabling it or, better, to configure the security profile.

Comment: Hi Artur, no I don't, I tried to use other ports and the problem persists...

Comment: Hi gile, I'll learn how to do that and try it. When it's done, I will come back with updates, thanks for helping!

Comment: It worked gile! Thank you so much for you contribution. https://wiki.debian.org/AppArmor/HowToUse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you confirmed it, I write the comment as answer.

Problem is due to **apparmor**.
Try disabling it or, better, to configure the security profile